# Spring Data REST Many to Many failing: working as One to Many

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two entities with Spring Data REST:
"Phase" the parent and "Subscription" the child in a Many to Many relationship.
I made using this article as a reference: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships

Phase Entity:

```
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "phases_subscriptions", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "phase_id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subscription_id"))
    @Getter @Setter
    private List<Subscription> subscriptions;
```

Subscription Entity:

```
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "subscriptions")
    @Getter @Setter
    private List<Phase> phases;
```

subscription.sql

```
phase int,
CONSTRAINT fk_subscription_phase FOREIGN KEY subscriptionPhase (phase) 
REFERENCES phase (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

With these I got the following results:

- GET http://localhost:8080/subscriptions/ created subscription
- GET http://localhost:8080/phases/ created phase
- On terminal(not on postman) curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:text/uri-list" --data-binary "http://localhost:8080/subscriptions/1" http://localhost:8080/phases/1/subscriptions
  Subscription 1 is now in a relationship with phase 1
- GET http://localhost:8080/phases/1/subscriptions I get the subscription 1
- GET http://localhost:8080/subscriptions/1/phases I get the phase 1

Now the issues:

- If I try to add a 2nd subscription to phase, I just override and now only subscription 2 has the relationship
- Only the table(created by spring) phases_subscriptions has both ids, in the subscription table it's stills NULL in the phase column
- I also want to use postman to create these new relationships, in one to many for example I can just use: PATCH {"phases": "phase 1 URL"} at Subscription 1 URL

Comment: "Only the table(created by spring) phases_subscriptions has both ids, in the subscription table it's stills NULL in the phase column". . . that's expected, the table 'phases_subscriptions' is the table responsible for joining both entities, this is the expected behavior in a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: yes, I know, but I cannot add more than one subscription per phase, it overrides, that's the issue

Comment: I'd recommend to: verify that you update the bi-directional references in your domain model correctly, depending on which side you set the value. What you describe in issues sounds exactly like the change on one side is not propagated to the other. Alternatively (and my actual suggestion): Avoid the bidirectional relationship in the first place, as they're very error-prone to implement, causing subtle issues like these.

If you have the time, feel free to create a reproducer project and file an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/issues

Answer (score 0):

I solved only changing the HTTP verb from PUT to PATCH, like this:
curl -i -X PATCH -H "Content-Type:text/uri-list" --data-binary "http://localhost:8080/subscriptions/2" http://localhost:8080/phases/1/subscriptions